# IF, OR and IFERROR function in excel

Tags: excel

```
 Column_A        Column_B       New (Expecting result for this situation)
  #N/A             #N/A             Manual Posting
```

My function has problem for the last syntax"IFERROR(IFERROR(....)" . Currently, I get #N/A for the "New" column. However, I want to get "Manual Posting" instead.

My syntax:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(B1,A1)="Bank BPH",IFERROR(B1,A1)="GE Budapest Bank"),"GECapital",IF(IFERROR(B1,A1)="Avio Aero","GE Aviation",IFERROR(IFERROR(B1,A1),"Manual Posting")))
```

Comment: What's this supposed to be doing?  `IFERROR(D7,C7)`  do you mean for this:  `OR(IFERROR(D7),IFERROR(C7))`  ??

Comment: @Ditto  IFERROR(D7,C7) means If D7 is error, and then it will return to C7. IFERROR(IFERROR(D7,C7),"Manual Posting"). It means if D7 and C7 are both error, it will return "Manual Posting".

Comment: oh ok .. I haven't used that one much, so thought you were trying to do OR in there .. my bad .. :)

Comment: @Ditto No worries. Just feel free to play with it. I just don't know why I can't get my result.

Comment: what do D7 and c7 point to ? your example data isn't clear on that ??

Comment: @Ditto Oh. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure out the correct syntax. I used to put the "AND(ISERROR(B18),ISERROR(A18)),"Manual Posting" to the end. However, I moved it at the beginning, it seems the problem can be solved.

```
 =IF(AND(ISERROR(B18),ISERROR(A18)),"Manual Posting",IF(OR(IFERROR(B18,A18)="Bank BPH",IFERROR(B18,A18)="GE Budapest Bank"),"GE Capital",IF(IFERROR(B18,A18)="Avio Aero","GE Aviation",IFERROR(B18,A18))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, working it out I think I can explain.

`IFERROR(x,y)` returns value x, unless it's an error, then it returns y .. (even if it is an error).

You then take result of that, and compare it to a string:

`IFERROR(A1,B1)="Bank BPH"`

Assuming valid values, that expression will, of course, return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

If both A1 and B1 are error, however, what happens ??

What is the result of:
`#ERR="string"` ??

answer: an error ... 
so what does the IF do with an error? it's neither true, nor false.

You can simplify the situation to just this expression to see what's going on:

`=IFERROR(A1,B1)="Bank BPH"`

it returns an error.
Neither true nor false.

You're going to need another check condition for an error and how to handle it ..

perhaps:

`=IF(AND(ISERROR(A1),ISERROR(B1)), "Manual post", IFERROR(A1,B1)="Bank BPH")`

might do the trick ??

Comment: Let me give you more details about what I want. 1. If column B has value, then I will just return value in column B; 2. If column B is error #N/A, then I will look at column A; 3. If column A has value, there are 3 situations: 1st if column A is either "Bank BPH" or "GE Budapest Bank", I will return "GE Capital"; 2nd if column A is "Avio Aero", then I will return "GE Aviation"; If it is not the first 2 situations, I will just return the value in column A; 4. If column A,B are both error, I will return "Manual Posting".